# How to get dashed or dotted grid (\tkzGrid) in tkz-fct?

Tags: tkz-fct

How to get dashed or dotted grid (`\tkzGrid`) in `tkz-fct`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the `\tkzGrid` call in a scope with the desired properties:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmax=4, ymax=2]
    \begin{scope}[dashed]
        \tkzGrid
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: rendering]