# tkz-fct: How to set line style of a tkzGrid

Tags: tikz-styles, tkz-fct, tkz-base

I'm using the tkz-fct package and I'd like to change the appereance of the grid issued with the command `\tkzGrid` , for example switch from solid to dotted lines.
So far I managed only to change the color of the grid lines with the following MWE, (not  minimal really, since I could drop the function plot).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
 \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \tkzInit[xmin=-5,xmax=4,ymin=-4,ymax=5]
       \tkzGrid[color=yellow,style=dashed,line width=2pt]
       \tkzFct[color=red,ultra thick]{(-x**2-2*x+3)} 
       \tkzAxeXY 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
 \end{document}
```

I am aware that I can put \tkzGrid in a scope environment like suggested in the answer at
[link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369238/how-to-get-dashed-or-dotted-grid-tkzgrid-in-tkz-fct) but I think that something like a `\tikzset{grid style/.style={draw (or color) = yellow,line pattern=dotted}}` would be more appropriate.

I couldn't find anything else searching through tex.stack exchange or in the tkz-fct tutorial.

---

Edit on 2024 january 4-th. A strange behaviour arises when I put `\tkzAxeXY` after `\tkzFct`; axes' graduations get red.

---

Tried to add some options to `\tkzGrid`, it doesn't occur any error but grid lines don't get dashed; `line width` and `color` are affected instead.

Comment: The scope idea seems to do the trick. However, it may be a good idea to contact the author, see link in the manual. Either grid options are largely ignored, or there's a hidden way to use them. All are reasons enough to talk about it and perhaps introduce changes, e.g. in the manual.

Comment: The best method is to use scope. `tkz-fct` is a fairly rudimentary package. It allows users to create their own code with TikZ. Since the creation of this package, `pgfplots` has appeared, which is complete and perfect, so I don't think I'll be reviewing the code.

Comment: @Alain Thank you, after all scope environment is simple enough.

Comment: @Antonio Perhaps when `tkz-elements` is well advanced, I'll make a more complete version but with `lualatex` and without `gnuplot`.

Comment: @Alain Matthes Dear Alain, I'd like to ask why running my code gives the number labels along the axes in red instead of default black color. I suspect that this behaviour is triggerd by putting `\tkzAxeXY` after `tkzFct[color=red]`. Unfortunately I cannot post images yet.

Comment: you need to put `\tkzAxeXY` before  `tkzFct[color=red]` but it is possible to put it after `tkzFct` if you put this line either in a scope or simply in a `{ ....}` group.

Answer (score 0):

Be plain, be simple.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[cyan,dotted] (-5,-2) grid (3,5);
\draw[->] (-5,0)--(3,0) node[below left]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-2)--(0,5) node[below left]{$y$};

\begin{scope}
\clip (-5,-2) rectangle (3,5);   
\draw[red,ultra thick,smooth] plot[domain=-4:3] (\x,-\x*\x-2*\x+3); 
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: That’s exactly the way I did it until now. For simple/pedagogical graphs I find `tkz-base/fct` more convenient though. For example there is no need for clipping since `\tikzinit` suffices. Furthermore, things start to become messy if you need ticks and graduations on coordinate axes. Thanks a lot anyway.